# How to schedule azcopy on windows task schedueler?

Tags: windows, azure, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, azcopy

**Goal**
Syncing my virtual drive (Azure file share) to a Azure blob storage container

**Solution**
For this solution i'm using azcopy. When i run azcopy with my create batch file, everyting is running correctly.

But i also want to schedule this, like every night.
For this i will use windows tasks scheduler.

Windows tasks scheduler runs the bat file correctly. My bat file also creates a log file. The output in the logfile is different when i run manual vs by the task scheduler.

**Batch file:**

```
@echo off
IF EXIST C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tasks\azcopy_logs.txt (
    del C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tasks\azcopy_logs.txt
)
set LOGFILE=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tasks\azcopy_logs.txt
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG

SET source="Y:\my-folder"
echo %source%
SET dest=^"https://TEST.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/?sv=2019-02-02^&ss=bfqt^&srt=sco^&sp=rwdlacup^&se=2120-02-26T14:56:15Z^&st=2020-02-26T06:56:10Z^&spr=https^&sig=TEST^"

echo %dest%

azcopy.exe sync %source% %dest%


exit
```

**Ouput when running manual**

```
"Y:\my-folder"
"https://TEST.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2120-02-26T14:56:15Z&st=2020-02-26T06:56:10Z&spr=https&sig=TEST"

Job a84acee9-1796-f44b-4852-530d052db5a0 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\x\.azcopy\a84acee9-1796-f44b-4852-530d052db5a0.log


0 Files Scanned at Source, 0 Files Scanned at Destination
334 Files Scanned at Source, 672 Files Scanned at Destination, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0
The source and destination are already in sync.
```

**Ouput running by task scheduler**

```
"Y:\my-folder"
"https://TEST.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2120-02-26T14:56:15Z&st=2020-02-26T06:56:10Z&spr=https&sig=TEST"

Cannot perform sync due to error: sync must happen between source and destination of the same type, e.g. either file <-> file, or directory/container <-> directory/container
```

**Task scheduler xml definition**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-02-25T13:30:25.4791113</Date>
    <Author>my-user</Author>
    <URI>\azcopy\my task name</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2020-02-25T13:29:16</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>my-user-id</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tasks\azcopy.bat</Command>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tasks\</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve]. Please export your task to XML and [edit] your post include the contents of that file.

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes in `set dest=^"...`?

Comment: If i don't escape the queotes, azcopy also returns an error by running the batch file manual: `AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature fields not well formed.`

Comment: Try `set "dest=..."` instead.  Or just remove them.

Comment: And post your task!

Comment: `set "dest=..."` same result with task scheduler. My task action added to my initial question

Comment: Post an [mcve], not just the `Action` block from you task scheduler XML.

Comment: Updated my post with more information about the goal and the solution. Also my complete task scheduler xml added

Comment: Just to see if it eliminates the scheduled task failure: Change Scheduled task security options to: "Run only when user is logged on" and checkmark "Run with highest privileges".

Comment: To notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@som or @somebadhat` will both work. [Learn more about comments…](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem found and solved.

Windows task scheduler doesn't have permissions to the mounted azure file share drive.

**Solution:**
Changed source drive (SET source="Y:\my-folder") to UNC path (SET source="\TEST.file.core.windows.net\my-container\my-folder")

Comment: In my case (where I wanted to get files from Azure fileshare to local folder on VM) I had to set up whole path to azcopy (with letter drive and extension):

`$source = "https://<fsname>.file.core.<fsdomain>/$fileshareName$sasToken"
 $dest = "$FolderName"
 D:\azcopy.exe sync $source $dest --recursive | Out-File $logFilePath -Append`.

Without it the script was working itself, but without azcopy inside of it (no logs from azcopy in `.azcopy` folder)