# Batch file for auto backup

Tags: batch-file, azure-sql-database, scheduled-tasks, backup

I have a server in which I'm running an SQL Server Express DB and an Azure blob i which I Upload each morning the backup of the SQL Server.

Now, I've been able to automate the backup via a mix of SQL query + batch file and I have it scheduled into my task scheduler to run each night at 9:00pm, but I would like to move also a copy of the backup from the server to the Azure Storage.

I've already tryed a batch file in task scheduler:

```
echo off
copy "Z:\Backup\SQLBackup\" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\DailyStep_bck.bak"
```

But it doesn't work by itself, only if I run it manually.
Each day the current copy should replace the older one, I don't need retention of old bacups for now.

I've tryed also robocopy and it also doesn't work... could someone tell me what am I missin?

the task is running as administrator with the "Run wether the admin is loged in or not" option.

thanks for your help.

Comment: To begin with, I'm going to suggest that you open up a Command Prompt window, type `copy /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read what is presented. Then I'd ask you to repeat that, but this time entering, `robocopy /?`, instead`.

Comment: I would use `robocopy` instead, as mentioned by @Compo, run `robocopy /?` and specifically look at the `/MIR` portion of the help.

Comment: if no user is logged in, surely there aren’t mapped resources, is `Z:` a mapped drive?  try full  `unc path` or use `net use ..`or `pushd ..` at the top of the script to create a temporary mapped resource. see help for `net use` and `pushd` for further information. also, if you use `pushd` is best practice to use `popd` too

Comment: also, you may find this useful to speed up copy tasks https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8425&p=55881#p55881

Comment: Is that you have mount azure blob on your server?

Comment: Hello all, the short answer is Yes, I've mounted the Azure blob as the Z: Unit.
As far as I know,robocopy is used for folder copy, not for files.
It is worth a try, what would be the syntax for the robocopy script?
Also I've just tryed to add the /Y to the current copy script, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Core88 Could you please tell me how you mount blob. I cannot do that?

Comment: @JimXu, I've crated a .ps1 file with the folowing script inside.
`$acctKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "[Azure_key_string]" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "Azure\[Azure_account]", $acctKey
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\[Azure_account].file.core.windows.net\[blob_name]" -Credential $credential –Persist`

Comment: According to the script you provide, you mount Azure file share on your server. So you cannot upload file to azure blob, you just can upload file to azure file share.

Comment: @JimXu
So I canno do the auto upload of the .bak file in any way?

Comment: @Core88 If you want to upload file to azure blob, I think you can use the acopy:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10

Comment: @JimXu already tryed, but it keeps returning the error message "wrong argument number..."

Comment: Could you please provide your command?

Comment: Hello @JimXu, sorry for the late reply, this is the script:
-----
azcopy copy 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\*.bak' 'https://[Azure_account].file.core.windows.net/storage/Backup/SQLBackup/[backup_file].bak' --recursive=true

Comment: @Core88 Please try to create sas token for your file share. Then use  `zcopy copy 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup*.bak' 'https://[Azure_account].file.core.windows.net/storage/Backup/SQLBackup/[backup_file].bak?<sas token>` :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files

Comment: @JimXu thank you very much, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize the solution as below.

Windows task scheduler doesn't have permissions to the mounted azure file share drive. So we need to use the path `https://[Azure_account].file.core.windows.net/storage/Backup` to access Azure file share. Besides, if you want to implement auto-upload, you can use [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/files/toc.json#download-azcopy).

For example

1. [Create a sas token for the file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature)
2. Script

```
azcopy copy 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup*.bak' 'https://[Azure_account].file.core.windows.net/storage/Backup/SQLBackup/[backup_file].bak?<sas token>
```

3. Create a schedule task

For more details, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409053/how-to-schedule-azcopy-on-windows-task-schedueler) and [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-developer-blog/windows-scheduler-task-to-backup-your-data-to-storage-account/ba-p/1067860)

Comment: Yes, I've one it at the end, I had to generate the SAS token since I didn't had that.
Now it works properly, thank you very much for your help, it was really appreciated.!!!

Comment: @Core88 Since it is useful for you, could you please accept it as an answer?